# Mostrar sugerencias mientras se escribe en textbox

Tags: c#, webforms

quisiera saber còmo puedo mostrar sugerencias de acuerdo a lo que se va escribiendo en un textbox?

Por ejemplo:

Tengo un textbox para buscar nombres, si escribo la letra C, me muestre sugerencias de nombres que contengan la letra C. La busqueda es consumiendo un webservice.

Comment: que tipo de aplicacion se trata es winform, web ?

Comment: La app es una web form

Answer (score 2):

Yo necesite algo similar y lo hice usando el framework de mdbootstrap, pero para tu caso podrás usar librerías jQuery como http://easyautocomplete.com/. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. la idea es:

1. Crear un metodo para realizar la consulta en la tabla de la base de 
       datos.
2. llamar este método en el PageLoad y llenar la variable
       publica `funcList` con el resultado, para luego pasarselos al script.

.aspx

```
//ClientIDMode=Static para poder seleccionarlo con jQuery o puedes usar <%= txtSearchFunc.ClientID%>--%>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchFunc" runat="server" CssClass="mdb-autocomplete" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

.cs

```
 public string funcList = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    GetFuncList_Onload();
    }

    private void GetFuncList_Onload()     //carga el listado de los usuarios 
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Web2017_CS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT '\"' + REPLACE(REPLACE(fun_Email, CHAR(10),''), CHAR(13),'') + '\"' AS fun_Email FROM FUNC WHERE fun_Estado = 1", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

                var data = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new { ZupaStringAba = row["fun_Email"].ToString() + "," });
                foreach (var row in data)
                {
                    string SuggestionList1 = row.ZupaStringAba;
                    funcList += SuggestionList1;
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

javascript

```
<script>
   var list = [<%= funcList%>];
   $('#txtSearchFunc').mdb_autocomplete({
       data: list
    });        
 </script>
```

Comment: Consumiendo un web service funciona parecido?

Comment: Si sería parecido, consumes el webservices, obtienes el listado y se lo pasas a la variable publica, tal vez tengas que usar Ajax para refrescar la lista, o cuando hagas el postback volver al llamar el método  `GetFuncList_Onload();` para que se recargue la lista.

Answer (score 2):

podes utiliza el autocomplete de jqueryui:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

```
<input id="nombres">
<script>
  $(function() {

    $("#nombres").autocomplete({
      source: function(req, res) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://miWebService/AutoCompletarNombre",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function(data) {
            response(data);
          }
        });
      },
      //Aca pones el largo minimo a partir del cual se dispara la consulta
      minLength: 2, 
    });
  });
</script>
```